# MongoDB - list one document from each serial number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have four documents. Each document has a serial number, and I want to get one document from each serial number. It should be the last document of it serial number.
for example.
Collect Name:Sales

```
Serial  name  date
10000   A     2014
10000   B     2015
20000   C     2014 
20000   C     2015
```

I want to list 2nd document for serial 10000 and fourth document for serial 20000.

```
 var list=Sales.findOne({}, {
      sort: {date:-1}
    });
```

How can I do this? I tried many things but I couldn't do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include the code with what you have tried thus far and the kind of expected output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do that through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) as below

```
> db.sales.aggregate([
               // sort by date
               {$sort: {date: -1}}, 
               // group by `Serial`, and retrieve the first element from group result, which is latest date.
               {$group: {_id: '$Serial', 
                         name: {$first: '$name'}, 
                         date: {$first: '$date'}
               }}
        ]);
```